# Prove that $f(x)=0$ has no rational solutions

Tags: polynomials, divisibility

$f(x)$ $\in$ $Z[X]$ monic polynomial of degree $n$

$k,p$ $\in$ $N$

If none of the numbers $f(k), f(k+1), \ldots , f(k+p)$ is disivible by $p+1$, then $f(x)=0$ has no rational solutions.

Comment: What have you tried? What theorems do you think will be useful but have not had success using yet?

Comment: Must the polynomial have integer coefficients? rational coefficients? real coefficients? Esp since we likely want $f(k)$ to be an integer.

Comment: I think the right statement would be : $f(x) \in \mathbb Z[x]$ monic, $k, p$ integers and $p$ prime. Right?

Comment: I believe that $p$ doesn't need to be a prime. @MFG please edit the question to include integer coefficients.

Comment: Yes, $p$ - doesn't need to be a prime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** $\ $ Suppose not, so $\,f(x)\,$ has a rational root $\,r.\,$ By the [Rational Root Test,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) a rational root of a $\rm{\color{#c00}{monic}}$ polynomial $\in\Bbb Z[x]\,$ must be an integer, since the test implies that the denominator of a reduced rational root divides the leading coefficient $\color{#c00}{(= 1)}.\,$ Since  the $\,m = p+1\,$ consecutive integers $\,k,k\!+\!1,\ldots,k\!+\!p\,$ form a complete system of residues mod $\,m,\,$ the integer root $\,r\,$ must be congruent to one them, say $\, r \equiv k\!+\!i\pmod m.\, $ Therefore

$\quad{\rm mod}\ m\!:\,\ k\!+\!i\equiv r\ \Rightarrow\ f(k\!+\!i)\equiv f(r) \equiv 0,\ $  i.e. $\ p\!+\!1 = m\mid f(k\!+\!i),\, $ contra hypothesis.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** By the rational root theorem, all rational roots are integers.

**Hint:** $f(n+m) \equiv f(n) \pmod{m}$

Answer (score 1):

Assume by contradiction that $f$ has a rational solution $a$. Then since $f$ is monic, the solution is integer.

Now, one of the numbers $k-a, k+1-a,.., k+p-a$ is divisible by $p+1$. Hence

$$p+1| (k+i)-a | P(k+i)-P(a)=P(k+i)$$

contradiction.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm lost during your demonstration :-(